# How to Select selected items in edit mode Multiselect Dropdown in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Select my selected items in edit mode. I am using multi-select dropdown as follow:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.BRAND_ID, Model.BRAND_List, null,
      new { @class = "inputbox", multiple = "multiple",@style="height:120px;"})
```

No when I open my form in edit mode it always highlight single item not multi my values are multiple from DB.

This is what I tried so far:

```
public List<Brands> BrandsList() {
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt;
    List<Brands> BrandsList = new List<Brands>();

    ds = Cls_EM_Admin_BRANDS.getBrands();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    //BrandsList.Add(new Brands { Brand_ID = 0, Brand_Name ="Select"});
    int i = 0;

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows) {
        BrandsList.Add(new Brands { 
            Brand_ID = Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"]),
            Brand_Name = item["Title"].ToString()
        });
    }
    return BrandsList;
}

if (ID != null) {  ///this condition runs on edit
    var objModel_Brands = new EM_BrandAdmin_Model()
        .Get_BrandAdmin_DATA(Convert.ToInt32(ID));
    BrandsSelect_List = new SelectList(
    BrandsList(), "Brand_ID", "Brand_Name", objModel_Brands.BrandID);
    objModel_Brands.BRAND_List = BrandsSelect_List;

    return view(objModel_Brands)
}

public EM_BrandAdmin_Model Get_BrandAdmin_DATA(Int32 P_ADMIN_ID) {
    try {
        objModel_BrandAdmin = new EM_BrandAdmin_Model();
        cmd = new OracleCommand("SP_BRAND_ADMIN_LIST", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ADMIN_ID", OracleDbType.Int32))
            .Value = P_ADMIN_ID;

        cn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read()) {
            objModel_BrandAdmin = new EM_BrandAdmin_Model();
            objModel_BrandAdmin.ADMIN_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ADMIN_ID".ToUpper()]);
            objModel_BrandAdmin.BRAND_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BRAND_ID"]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        cn.Close();
        if (dr != null) {
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
    return objModel_BrandAdmin;
}
```

Comment: Bran_ID only set the single value..how is it possible to multiselected items

Answer (score 1):

In your model, change

```
public int BRAND_ID { get; set; }
public List<Brands> BRAND_List { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<int> BRAND_ID { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BRAND_List { get; set; }
```

In your view, change

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.BRAND_ID, Model.BRAND_List, null, new { @class = "inputbox", multiple = "multiple",@style="height:120px;"})
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BRAND_ID, Model.BRAND_List, null, new { @class = "inputbox", multiple = "multiple",@style="height:120px;"})
```

In your Brands class, add

```
public bool Selected { get; set; }
```

In your controller, change

```
BrandsList.Add(new Brands { Brand_ID = Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"]), Brand_Name = item["Title"].ToString() });
...
BrandsSelect_List = new SelectList(BrandsList(), "Brand_ID", "Brand_Name", objModel_Brands.BrandID);
```

to

```
BrandsList.Add(new Brands { Brand_ID = Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"]), Brand_Name = item["Title"].ToString(), Selected = true });
//Note: replace "true" above with code to retrieve the selection from the db
...
BrandsSelect_List = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (Brands b in BrandsList()){
    BrandsSelect_List.Add(new SelectListItem(){ Value = b.BRAND_ID, Text = b.Brand_Name, Selected = b.Selected }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uFAOcP).

However, I recommend you to use `ListBoxFor` instead of `DropDownListFor` as it will make your code much simpler. If you want to use `ListBoxFor` then ignore the solution above and do the following:

In your model, change

```
public int BRAND_ID { get; set; }
public List<Brands> BRAND_List { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<int> BRAND_ID { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BRAND_List { get; set; }
```

In your view, change

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.BRAND_ID, Model.BRAND_List, null, new { @class = "inputbox", multiple = "multiple",@style="height:120px;"})
```

to

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.BRAND_ID, Model.BRAND_List, new { @class = "inputbox", @style="height:120px;"})
```

In your controller, change

```
objModel_BrandAdmin.BRAND_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BRAND_ID"]);
```

to read a list of integers from the database, this list is your selection.

Here is a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPfC3m).

Comment: Actually it wont make anything 'selected' The `Selected` property is completely ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method. Its the value of the property (which needs to be `IEnumerable<int>`) that determines what is selected

Comment: It will select all values true...what if i have 1 true and 1 false ?

Comment: Yes, it will select all to true because of the `Selected = true`. I left a comment for you there that you must replace `true` above with code to retrieve the selection from the db. Have you done that? The selection should be saved in your db, so you need to retrieve it, but for testing, you can assign some items of the `BrandsList` to `false` and see how it works.

Comment: @RacilHilan. It will **NOT** select any options. Read my first comment! Its the value of `BRAND_ID` that determines what is selected. That's how model binding works.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Since you know, please post an answer so others can benefit from your knowledge. I've added demos to my answer that clearly proves that the `Selected` properly is **NOT** ignored and items get selected accordingly. The value of a single `int` property will work for the `DropDownListFor`, but the multiple `IEnumerable<int>` will not, unless you change it to `ListBoxFor`.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I've added demos for you.

Comment: @RacilHilan, And I have just forked your [DotNetFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMgpnt) to prove that setting the `Selected` property does not work (note that its set to `6` which is the last option but its ignored). The selected values are based on the values of `BRAND_ID`, not the `Selected` property. The only time the `Selected` property is respected if if you use it when generating a dropdownlist or listbox that is not bound to a property e.g. `ListBox("NotAProperty", Model.BRAND_List)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Seriously? 1) My first demo already proved that the `Selected` property is respected and does work. End of story. 2) Your example of passing the 6 is completely different from how I was setting it in my answer. Are you intentionally ignoring the difference to prove your point? 3) You used `ListBoxFor` instead of `DropDownListFor`. I've already explained the difference and the issue with `DropDownListFor`? Did you intentionally ignore that to prove your point? Please post an answer instead of polluting my answer with incorrect info.

Comment: Yes I'm serious! I repeat again, the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when you bind to a model property. And if your want to understand this, review the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs). When binding to a property, a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is generated where the `Selected` property is set based on the values of the property.

Comment: The purpose of my fork was to proved it that setting the `Selected` property is not respected, which it does. And if you just removed the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor in your fiddle you will see that it generates the same result.

Comment: And I don't need to add an answer. I made the initial comment to correct an error in your initial answer (i.e. _"Note: of course, this code will make all items selected"_) which was incorrect, but you have now removed it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't need to review the source code as I know how it works. Your argument is only correct if the property has values. If you comment the line `objModel_BrandAdmin.BRAND_ID = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5 };` in your fiddle, you will see that the last row #6 is selected according to the `Selected` property. If you read my answer carefully, I told him to add the `Selected` to the `Brands` class and get the selection from the db, so the `BRAND_ID` property will have no values to overwrite it. So your comment that the `Selected` property will be ignored, is incorrect in that case.

Comment: Wow, All I was trying to do was to correct a misconception you have. The reason that the last option is selected if you comment out that line is that `BRAND_ID` is `null` (the helper then falls back to a different overload). And if you used `objModel_BrandAdmin.BRAND_ID = new List<int>();` it will not be selected. But clearly your not interested in learning so I wont bother you anymore.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was answering the OP question, not learning. What is the misconception that I have? I know how the model binding works and I know that it overwrite the `Selected` property **if you pass it values**. That description from you is correct. However, as I mentioned, the `DropDownListFor` has an issue with multi-select, so my solution is not to pass it values and use the `Selected` property instead. Alternatively, using `ListBoxFor` is the preferred way if possible. Now, your comment *the helper then falls back to a different overload* is incorrect. Which overload?

Comment: `DropDownListFor()` does not have a issue with multi-select if your include the  `new { multiple = "multiple" }` attribute as OP is doing. It produces identical html as using `ListBoxFor()` - which is just more convenient (and as you stated yourself, makes the code simpler) and understandable.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's not about the HTML that it generates. Go to your fiddle where the rows 1,4,5 are selected, and change the `ListBoxFor` to `DropDownListFor`. Notice that all the selection disappear. That's the issue I'm referring to. Do you know why or how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. As to why, the key is in the source code - `object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string[])) : htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));` in the `private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal()` method. `DropDownListFor()` passes `allowMultiple = false` and so `defaultValue` is null because it cannot make the conversion.

Comment: As a result, the `GetSelectListWithDefaultValue()` method is not called and a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is not generated. Which is why as you correctly point out, its recommended to use `ListBoxFor()` (and not set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` or `SelectList`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for digging in the code, but do you agree with me that passing `allowMultiple = false` when we clearly set it to `new { multiple = "multiple" }` is a bug? That's the issue I was referring to and that's why I solved it as in my answer. We both agree that using `ListBoxFor` is the way to go, but I worked on 4 projects where `ListBoxFor` was not available so I had to fix the `DropDownListFor` like that. I don't know the OP's situation so I gave him both ways.

Comment: Not sure I would call it a bug. After all there is a method `DropDownListFor()` for generating a dropdownlist and a method `ListBoxFor()` for generating a listbox so why fight it (and to take that to extremes, look at [RadioButtonFor(...., new { type = "checkbox" })](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846349/how-to-display-two-partialviews-in-the-same-view-in-mvc)).

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's insane :-). Thank you Stephen, for the interesting discussion.

Comment: M so glad to see this..Thank you All