# How to display two partialviews in the same view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I display two partial views in the same view? In my controller I have two methods that both returns partialview.  I want these methods together in one view.

In my controller i have this:

```
   public ActionResult CountCars()
    {           
        var result = this.Data.Cars.All()                    
            .Select(t => new CarsViewModel
            {
                CategoryName = t.Name,
                CategoryCount = t.Category.Count()
            });
        return PartialView("_ChooseCarsPartialViewLayout", result.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult ChooseCity()
    {
        var view = this.Data.Cities.All()
            .Select(x => new CityViewModel
            {
                CityName = x.Name,
                CountCities = x.City.Count()
            });

        return PartialView("_ChooseCarsPartialViewLayout", view.ToList());                   
    }
```

_ChooseCarsPartialViewLayout

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.City.CityViewModel> <div class="container">
<div class="well">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>?</h4>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var cars = Model.ElementAt(i);

                        <label>@cars.CategoryName <span class="badge">@cars.CategoryCount</span></label>
                        @Html.RadioButton(cars.CategoryName,
                                 cars.CategoryId,
                            new
                            {
                                id = "radio",
                                type = "checkbox"

                            })

                    }
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Hvor vil du jobbe?</h4>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var city = Model.ElementAt(i);

                        <label>@city.CityName <span class="badge">@city.CountCities</span></label>
                        @Html.RadioButton(city.CityName,
                            city.CityId,
                            new
                            {
                                id = "radio",
                                type = "checkbox"

                            })

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I run the solution it just display an error that says.

> Value cannot be null or empty.
>   Parameter name: name
>
> Line 18:                             @Html.RadioButton(cars.CategoryName,

But if I had two different partial views then it works great, but I want to have this in the same partialview.

Also I have this Html.Action in _Layout to render the partialviews

```
 @Html.Action("ChooseCity", "Home")
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your title.  Read the exception message.  [RadioButtonFor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Object,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary{System.String,System.Object}%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a ViewModel called `CityViewModel` (though I'll name it `RadiosVM` I would create a few EditorFor templates.

Use a composite model as [user1672994 mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33847097/209259) although it can be made more generic and reusable.   A ViewModel should encapsulate all (there are exceptions) the data necessary to render a view.

```
public class RadiosVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<RadioVM> Radios { get; set; }
}

public class RadioVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class SomePageVM // whatever
{
  public RadiosVM CarRadios { get; set; }
  public RadiosVM CityRadios { get; set; }

  // ... other properties
}
```

Don't spin up another controller just to display a model  (that is inefficient), unless the controller is doing things that have absolutely nothing to do with the current controller and/or you plan on caching that view.

```
public class SomeController
{

  public ActionResult SomePage()
  {
    var model = new SomePageVM();
    model.CarRadios = GetCarRadios;
    model.CityRadios = GetCityRadios;
    return View(model);
  }

  private RadiosVM GetCarRadios()
  {           
    var result = new RadiosVM()
    {
      Name = "Cars",
      Radios = this.Data.Cars.All()                    
        .Select(t => new RadioVM
        {
          CategoryName = t.Name,
          CategoryCount = t.Category.Count()
        })
        .ToList();
    }
      return result;
  }

  public RadiosVM ChooseCity()
  {
    var result = new RadiosVM ()
    {
      Name = "Cars",
      Radios = this.Data.Cities.All()                    
        .Select(t => new RadioVM
        {
          CategoryName = t.Name,
          CategoryCount = t.Category.Count()
        })
        .ToList();
    }
      return result;
}
```

Views:

SomePage.cshtml

```
@Model SomePageVM  

<div class="well">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CarRadios)
    <div/>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CityRadios)
    <div/>

// ...
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RadiosVM.cshtml
or
/Views/SomeController/EditorTemplates/RadiosVM.cshtml

```
@Model RadiosVM

<div class="form-group">
  <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</h4>

  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">

  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Radios)

</div>
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RadioVM.cshtml
or
/Views/SomeController/EditorTemplates/RadioVM.cshtml

```
@Model RadioVM

<label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
  <span class="badge">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Count)</span>
</label>
@Html.RadioButton(model.Name, 
  model.Id,  // You have no code that references this, I don't know...
  new
  {
    id = "radio",  // so **ALL** radios are named 'id'??  not valid
    type = "checkbox"
  })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!. But why do I need EditorFor templates?

Comment: [Brad Wilson - MVC Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have followed your code, and it seems to work great! :) And thank you @user1672994

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the partial view model which is strongly typed of `IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.City.CityViewModel>` which does not contain the declaration of `CategoryName`. So, you should create a Composite Model which would return `Cars` and `Citis` to partial view.

```
public class CompositeModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.City.CityViewModel> Cars { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.City.CarsViewModel> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Now change your view as

```
@model CompositeModel
<div class="container">
<div class="well">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>?</h4>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var cars = Model.Cars.ElementAt(i);

                        <label>@cars.CategoryName <span class="badge">@cars.CategoryCount</span></label>
                        @Html.RadioButton(cars.CategoryName,
                                 cars.CategoryId,
                            new
                            {
                                id = "radio",
                                type = "checkbox"

                            })

                    }
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Hvor vil du jobbe?</h4>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cities.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var city = Model.Cities.ElementAt(i);

                        <label>@city.CityName <span class="badge">@city.CountCities</span></label>
                        @Html.RadioButton(city.CityName,
                            city.CityId,
                            new
                            {
                                id = "radio",
                                type = "checkbox"

                            })

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Per has to change the implementation. If you see his code, he returns the same partial view for both actions but the partial view is type of CitiViewModel. Since, cshtml does not compile (unless set by build properties) so exception will be thrown at run time when process tries to compile the view first time.

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks so much for your answer. I have followed your code, and again I get some problem with debugging it. "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: source"

Comment: on which line you got the problem?

Comment: @user1672994  Line 13: for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cities.Count(); i++)

Comment: Is the Cities object is null? Basically, you should generate input buttons only if Model or it's properties are not null. If you still having two actions then you would be returning only one property in Model (either Cities or Cars) so you should put the null check. Another point - you can make only action to return aggregate Model to partial view.